# How can I get Faye working on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that handles live notifications with Faye and whilst it works in development I can't seem to get it working in production. The problem is that there are two servers/ports, one for the rails application and one for the Faye server.

Now when my faye procfile has the following:

```
web:  bundle exec thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV -R faye.ru start
```

The faye server runs, but the application server doesn't run..

and when the faye procfile has:

```
web:  bundle exec thin -p 9292 -e production -R faye.ru start
```

then the application runs, but the Faye.js file cannot be found.

So, how can I get both the application server, and the Faye server to run on Heroku?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to do the same now.